# Populating NSTableView from multiple NSArray records in one go

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

If I have a one to many relationship, how would I go about populating the NSTableView with such data that is found in an NSArray?

Say I have a data item called "Alphabet", and I want that when a user selects it out of a list, the return value(s) in :

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

are the letters of the alphabet in different rows, one underneath the other.

Can that be done?
Thanks!

Comment: I've tried calling the method above directly in a loop and passing the loop counter as the rowIndex parameter above..

I'm not sure I'm supposed to call the method directly though (apart from the fact that it isn't working), as I think that is the job of the [tableName reloadData];

Comment: I have also tried to return the array itself, but I only get a "(" in the first row as a result..

Comment: You need to read the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html) because at the moment you're just guessing.

Comment: I know how a table view works and I've read the documentation. I've asked here because I couldn't find an answer. There is no need to be condescending.

Comment: I'm not trying to be. You didn't mention that you've read the documentation, and I couldn't know that you had.

Comment: I should have mentioned that then.. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either assign an object as the table view's `datasource` and have that object conform to the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol, or you need to use an `NSArrayController` and Cocoa bindings.

If you use a datasource, implement the `numberOfItemsInTableView:` method and return the `count` of your array. You must also implement `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`:

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    if(rowIndex > -1)
    {
        return [yourArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Should that be rowIndex instead of row in the if statement?

Comment: The problem with the above code, is that (row > -1) is never returning true, even though the numberOfItemsInTableView: is returning the count of the array (1000+)..

Therefore I am getting 1000+ records of the same value.

Comment: Yes, it should be `rowIndex`, that was a typo. Fixed. Can you post your code?